# Get url's by div with python and beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to use `BeautifulSoup` and `Selenium` to scrape pdf's off a website

I have tried using the `find_all()` function in different ways but do not get the results I need.

Basically what I want to be able to do is get the links by each **Quarter (e.g Q4 2014 – Q3 2015)** and **Country (Malaysia, Indonesia, etc)** so that I can scrape the pdf's into a folder by Quarter and then a subfolder in there for the Countries.

Below is the snippet of html for that site:

```
</div><a class="accord-header accord-header-5049 accord-header-supply-chain-resources"><div>Supply Chain</div></a><div class="accord-body accord-body-5049 accord-body-supply-chain-resources" style="display: none;"><ul>
<li class="folder">
                    <div>Q4 2014 – Q3 2015</div>
                    <ul style="display: none;">
                        <li class="folder">
                            <div>Indonesia</div>
                            <ul style="display: none;">
                                <li class="document"><a href="/sustainability/wp-content/themes/wilmar/sustainability/assets/../downloads/wilmar/resource/Indonesia/MNA KualaTanjung_L1--160122.pdf">MNA KualaTanjung</a></li>
                                <li class="document"><a href="/sustainability/wp-content/themes/wilmar/sustainability/assets/../downloads/wilmar/resource/Indonesia/MNA Paya Pasir_L1 --160122.pdf">MNA Paya Pasir</a></li>
                                <li class="document"><a href="/sustainability/wp-content/themes/wilmar/sustainability/assets/../downloads/wilmar/resource/Indonesia/MNA Pulo Gadung_L1 --160122.pdf">MNA Pulo Gadung</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="folder">
                            <div>Malaysia</div>
                            <ul style="display: none;">
                                <li class="document"><a href="/sustainability/wp-content/themes/wilmar/sustainability/assets/../downloads/wilmar/resource/Malaysia/BEO_L1 -- 160122.pdf">BEO Bintulu</a></li>
                                <li class="document"><a href="/sustainability/wp-content/themes/wilmar/sustainability/assets/../downloads/wilmar/resource/Malaysia/LDEO_L1 -- 160122.pdf">LDEO Lahad Datu</a></li>

                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="folder">
                            <div>Destination Countries</div>
                            <ul style="display: none;">
                                <li class="document"><a href="/sustainability/wp-content/themes/wilmar/sustainability/assets/../downloads/wilmar/resource/Destination/Bangladesh_160122 -- new.pdf">Bangladesh</a></li>
                                <li class="document"><a href="/sustainability/wp-content/themes/wilmar/sustainability/assets/../downloads/wilmar/resource/Destination/China- Oleochemical_160122 -- new.pdf">China- Oleochemical</a></li>
                                <li class="document"><a href="/sustainability/wp-content/themes/wilmar/sustainability/assets/../downloads/wilmar/resource/Destination/China- Specialty Fats_160122 -- new.pdf">China- Specialty Fats</a></li>
                                <li class="document"><a href="/sustainability/wp-content/themes/wilmar/sustainability/assets/../downloads/wilmar/resource/Destination/Europe_Brake -- 160122 -- new.pdf">Europe_Brake</a></li>
                                <li class="document"><a href="/sustainability/wp-content/themes/wilmar/sustainability/assets/../downloads/wilmar/resource/Destination/Europe_Rotterdam -- 160122 -- new.pdf">Europe_Rotterdam</a></li>

                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="folder">
                    <div>Q1 – Q4 2015</div>
                    <ul style="display: none;">
                        <li class="folder">
                            <div>Indonesia</div>
                            <ul style="display: none;">
                                <li class="document"><a href="/sustainability/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/160427_MNA-KTJ_L1.pdf">MNA KualaTanjung</a></li>
                                <li class="document"><a href="/sustainability/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/160427_MNA-PG_L1.pdf">MNA Paya Pasir</a></li>
                                <li class="document"><a href="/sustainability/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/160427_MNA-PPS_L1.pdf">MNA Pulo Gadung</a></li>
                                <li class="document"><a href="/sustainability/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/160427_MNS-BTG_L1.pdf">MNS Bitung</a></li>

                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="folder">
                            <div>Malaysia</div>
                            <ul style="display: none;">
                            <li class="document"><a href="/sustainability/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/160427_BEO_L1.pdf">BEO Bintulu</a></li>
                            <li class="document"><a href="/sustainability/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/160427_LDEO_L1.pdf">LDEO Lahad Datu</a></li>
                            <li class="document"><a href="/sustainability/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/160427_NatOleo_L1.pdf">NatOleo Pasir Gudang</a></li>
                            <li class="document"><a href="/sustainability/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/160427_PGEO-Lumut_L1.pdf">PGEO Lumut</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="folder">
                            <div>Destination Countries</div>
                            <ul style="display: none;">
                                <li class="document"><a href="/sustainability/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/160427_Bangladesh_L1.pdf">Bangladesh</a></li>
                                <li class="document"><a href="/sustainability/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/160427_China-Oleochemical_L1.pdf">China- Oleochemical</a></li>
                                <li class="document"><a href="/sustainability/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/160427_China-Specialty Fats_L1.pdf">China- Specialty Fats</a></li>

                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
```

I could extract the urls on there with the code below but not able to differentiate them by Quarter and Country so that doesn't help me so much.

```
for li in soup.find_all(class_="document"):
    try:
        href = (li.a.get('href'))
        if re.search(match, href):
           links.append(href)
    except KeyError:
        pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page is being loaded with JavaScript so to get around that I just used Selenium to load the page and grab the html. I also modified the code to only target the supply chain section.

EDIT:

This new version keeps the same browser open, downloads the pdfs (to `download_dir` set near the top) and moves them into the correct directory structure. The directory tree will be created wherever this script is run.

Since the website seems to be employing anti-bot features, I randomized `time.sleep` from 3-9 seconds (could be easily changed). The other thing is that if the script stops for whatever reason, you should be able to pick back up from where the downloading stopped. The code checks to see if a file already exists in the proper directory and will only download it if it doesn't already exist.

In the interest of time (there seem to be 525 pdfs total), I only downloaded the pdfs from the first quarter directory for testing but if there are any errors farther down, let me know!

```
import os
import random
import shutil
import time
from collections import defaultdict
from urllib.parse import quote, urljoin

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.element import Tag
from selenium import webdriver

# Setup Chrome to download PDFs
download_dir = '/home/lettuce/Downloads'  # "D:\z_Temp\Wilmar_Traceability"  # for linux/*nix, download_dir="/usr/Public"
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
profile = {
    "plugins.plugins_list": [{
        "enabled": False,
        "name": "Chrome PDF Viewer"
    }],
    # Disable Chrome's PDF Viewer
    "download.default_directory": download_dir,
    "download.extensions_to_open": "applications/pdf"
}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", profile)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)

# Get page source of all PDF links
url = 'http://www.wilmar-international.com/sustainability/resource-library/'
driver.get(url)
page_html = driver.page_source

# Parse out PDF links and a structure for the folders
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html, 'lxml')
supply_chain = soup.select_one(
    '#text-wrap-sub > div.sub_cont_left > div > div > div > '
    'div.accord-body.accord-body-5049.accord-body-supply-chain-resources > ul'
)
result = {}
for li in supply_chain:
    if isinstance(li, Tag):
        quarter = li.div.text
        documents = defaultdict(list)
        for folder in li.find_all('li', class_='folder'):
            country = folder.div.text
            for document in folder.find_all('li', class_="document"):
                documents[country].append(document.a['href'])
        result[quarter] = documents


supply_chain_dir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'SupplyChain')
os.makedirs(supply_chain_dir, exist_ok=True)
for quarter, countries in result.items():
    # create quarter directory
    quarter_dir = os.path.join(supply_chain_dir, quarter)
    os.makedirs(quarter_dir, exist_ok=True)
    for country, documents in countries.items():
        # create country directory
        country_dir = os.path.join(quarter_dir, country)
        os.makedirs(country_dir, exist_ok=True)
        for document in documents:
            filename = document.split('/')[-1]
            if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(country_dir, filename)):
                # download pdf and move it to country directory
                driver.get(urljoin(url, quote(document)))
                time.sleep(random.randint(3, 9))
                shutil.move(
                    src=os.path.join(download_dir, filename),
                    dst=country_dir
                )

driver.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this @Delirious! The output looks great but unfortunately, when I run it on the full web page, i get this error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'` The full page when I am trying to get that info from is here [link](http://www.wilmar-international.com/sustainability/resource-library/). I am only interested in the **Supply Chain** part. Thanks so much again for you help!

Comment: Thanks so much, @Delirious Lettuce! Works great. I know I should probably have asked this in the initial question but I was just wondering if you know how I could quickly create folders from the dictionaries and run the links to download the pdf's using `selenium`?